# Reinstall Wordpress theme to fix error

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm having these error within a WordPress site I was working on:

```
Cannot redeclare class GDLR_WXR_Parser in /home/mysite/public_html/wp-content/plugins/goodlayers-importers/parsers.php
```

What happens with this error is that the pagebuilder elements is currently NOT displayed on the admin side of the homepage. In other words, the sections that was made using the pagebuilder on the homepage is now uneditable. The theme I was working on is Charity Hub by GoodLayers.

Now since I can't seem to resolve it and I'm way over the Support period of Themeforest, is it ok to reinstall the whole theme?

How about the pagebuilder elements that was used to create the homepage? Will the layout and contents not be retained after reinstalling?

Answer (score 0):

If page builder is a plug-in then try to reinstall it . 
And even if you reinstall the theme.. No page that you have created will be deleted instead it is good idea to reinstall the theme because if there is an error in the theme side then it will be removed ... But if you reinstall theme then do not reinstall the demo data..

Comment: Thank you. I'll mark this as the solution once I have reinstalled the theme.

Comment: Ok, thanks just make sure you do nothing else than reinstalling theme..